# Does VSCode not support java 15 yet?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Has vscode updated to allow java 15 yet? When I tried to update it, it didnt show any change.

Answer (score 0):

According to [VsCode Java twit](https://twitter.com/VSCodeJava/status/1306275380584763392) release is planned for the end of September. Here is [github issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1627) with the link to the latest CI build with Java 15 support.

Comment: thanks for the help! I swear I already wrote that and a mod deleted it, this site is so weird!